# Prove that if there is a nontrivial homomorphism from $D_n$ to G then the order of G is even.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

Let $D_n$ denote the dihedral group of order 2n. Let G be a finite group. Prove that if there is a nontrivial homomorphism from $D_n$ to G then the order of G is even.

I am thinking to use $D_n/ker(\phi)\simeq G$, but I am confuse to use this theorem because question is asking about homomorphism, not about isomorphism.

Anyone please suggest me some direction to think this question?

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ were odd, then we get that any even order element of $D_n$ must be mapped to the identity, else its image would generate an order $2$ subgroup of $G$, contradicting Lagranges theorem.

So now we just need to exhibit generators of $D_n$ of order $2$, since the the kernel must contain these, giving that the kernel is all of $D_n$.

I'll leave finding them to you, since it depends on your description of $D_n$, but such generators of order $2$ do exist.

Comment: If $n>2$, then $\{sr^i\}$ for $i=0,1,2,...n-1$ has order two. So the image generate order 2 subgroup. This is contradiction to Lagranges theorem.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: The logic goes that any order $2$ element must be in the kernel of this map, so any product of order $2$ elements must also be in the kernel. So then if in your description $\{sr^i\}$ all have order $2$, then they must all be in the kernel, so since these generate the whole group, then the kernel is everything, and the map is trivial.